# graphql-compose doesn't accept my args in the resolve method

Tags: graphql

I have an issue with a manual call of Resolver.resolve

```
const createEntityGroupResolver = EntityGroupTC.getResolver('createOne')
const createEntityResolver = EntityTC.getResolver('createOne')

const entityGroupCreate = new Resolver({
    name: 'entityGroupCreate',
    type: createEntityGroupResolver.type,
    args: createEntityGroupResolver.args,
    resolve: async ({ source, args, context, info }) => {
        const created = (await createEntityGroupResolver.resolve({ source, args, context, info })).record
        console.log("created entityGroup : ", created, " from args: ", args)
        const newArgs = {record:
                    {name: args.record.name, entityGroupId:created._id}}
        args.record.entityGroupId=created._id
        console.log("creating entity from args works: ", args, " but with newArgs it fails: ", newArgs)
        await createEntityResolver.resolve({source, newAargs, context, info})
        return created
    }
});
```

this code throws the following error:

> creating entity from args works:  { record:
>
> { name: 'fsgd1',
>
> ```
>  fb: 'jgjhgf',
>
>  web: 'kljh',
>
>  city: 'jk',
>
>  entityGroupId: 5bcf7ca2cd38080750b609f1 } }  but with newArgs it fails:  { record: { name: 'fsgd1', entityGroupId:
> ```
>
> 5bcf7ca2cd38080750b609f1 } }
>
> graphQl error :  Entity.createOne
>   resolver requires at least one value in args.record (node:1872)
>   [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects
>   via .inspect() is deprecated

For a myterious reaon, passing a modified args parameter works

```
    await createEntityResolver.resolve({source, args, context, info})
    return created
```

**I noticed args is logged with line breaks while newArgs is logged inline, I cannot understand why**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by "Pavel Chertorogov" in [this post](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose/issues/132), the issue was that I was missing the argument name that must be args and not newArgs (since I'm passing a map, not calling a function with params)

I must correct it this way:
- await createEntityResolver.resolve({source, newAargs, context, info})
+ await createEntityResolver.resolve({source, args: newArgs, context, info})